# XCode UIIMAGEVIEW display image from ftp

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ftp, uiimageview

How i can display image from my ftp to xcode (iphone app)
with uiimageview i can display a http image. But how i can do it with ftp

Answer (score 0):

Just use `NSURLConnection` with a path that starts with "ftp://" and it should just work. `NSURLConnection` supports `http`, `https`, `ftp` and `file` out of the box.